# IMPORTXML works in one Sheet but not in the other

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a question. I am using the IMPORTXML function in a Google Sheet that i just created and it works fine.

`=IMPORTXML("https://MYURL.COM","//div[@id='CONTENT']/div/span")`

When i paste the code in another sheet that someone shared with me i get an error. The owner of that file also gets an error when he tries.
`Error`
`Formula parse error.`
It does nog even tries to load. When i paste it, it instantly changes to the Error.

This code also is not working:

`=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")`

From the Google help page: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

My question, why does IMPORTXML work in one document, but not in the other.

Thank you!

Comment: You're obviously missing something. It's a syntax error. During the copy and paste, Something, like a whitespace character got added in the syntax giving it a parse error.  How about , Instead of pasting the code,Type it again from scratch.

Comment: I typed it over but still instant error. When i then copy and paste it into the working document it works..

Comment: Is the owner from a different country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing"; "//a/@href")
```

If the owner of that sheet has different locale settings, then you need to change `,` to `;`

Comment: That worked and I have no idea the why =), because: I am fetching data from an url located in the same country (I am sure of it). Also and more strange: I have another working ImportXML function in an older sheet created by me, but when I paste that function to a new sheet created by me it only works with the ";".

Comment: @Leonardo Could you explain in detail what's not working? Was there a error?

Comment: There was an error which was just an "#ERROR" (Formula parse error). But then when I replaced "," with ";" that worked. What I found very strange and it's still happening is the following: I have another sheet (not that first one where importXML only works with the ";") and there I have a working importXML with the ",". If I copy and paste the very same formula to the newer sheet it turns out the #ERROR so I have to replace the "," with ";" and have the formula working

Comment: @Leonardo Make sure your spreadsheet locale is the same on both spreadsheets.

Comment: That was the problem. I've checked and the older sheet had Location in blank while the newer one had "Brasil". Now I updated it to Brasil and the formula automatically replaced the "," with ";". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly on my end so your question is not accurate.
Here's a screenshot of a shared sheet from another account:

[image]

this was the one I executed which you have provided:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")
```

As mentioned in the comments, do a double check.

Comment: Hi noogui,

Thanks for the repond.  When i type this function in my own sheet it works, when i type it in the shared sheet it instantly gives an error.  It seems like it does not even tries to load.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: omg :D.    I was testing in chrome.  Tried IE and it works perfectly.   Strange but thanks!  UPDATE:  wrong sheet,  in the shared sheet still no luck..